# sending linked list to function

Tags: c, struct

hi im trying to write a program that will return the min value linked list and get 5 nodes linked list 
i have run it with the debugger and i have noticed that for some reason when i send the first node to my "search list" function the address and num values are just garbage so what am i doing wrong ?
in my defense im new to c :)

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item {
    int num;
    struct item *next;
}item; 

  struct item *addList(struct item **first, int num);
 int searchList(struct item *first);

int main() {

    struct item *first = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
    int n, i;
    printf("Enter 5 numbers: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        first = addList(&first, n);
    }

    printf("%d", searchList(first));

}


struct item *addList(struct item **first, int n) {

    struct item *new_node ;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct item));

    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("/nError, cant allocate memory (addList Function).");
        exit(1);
    }

    new_node->num = n;
    new_node->next = *first;
    *first = new_node;
}

int searchList(struct item *first) {

    struct item *p;
    int min=first->num;
    if (first == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next) {

        if (p->num < min)
            min = p->num;

    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: Where is `addList()` return value?

Comment: sorry its supposed to be void because im sending "first" address @chux

Comment: hooo i used its address and then given "first" and address like "addlist" have a return value

Comment: If `addList()` is supposed to return `void`, how is `first = addList(&first, n);` going to work?  Best to post true code that compiles without error.

Comment: its working now ! and your absolutely right ! i haven't noticed that i didn't changed it to void... is there any more advice about thing i could improve here ? i also changed "first" address in main to NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addList()` is supposed to return a value to assign it to `first` in `main()`. But you are not returning anything. But you don't need to return anything from `addList()` since the you are modifying the pointer `first` through a pointer to pointer. So, make it a function returning `void` and don't assign the return value of `addList()` to `first`.

You are expecting the list to be terminated with a NULL pointer. So, change

```
struct item *first = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
```

to

```
struct item *first = NULL;
```

which both fixes the *memory leak* and ensures the end of the list is a NULL pointer.

Comment: thank you very much! i have noticed it and your absolutely right that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

> struct item *addList(struct item **first, int num);
>
> first = addList(&first, n);

You should decide whether let addList() to manipulate its first argument (so growing the list), or make addList() to return the new element and let main() manipulate "first". In the former case, DONT assign first in the main; in the second case, you must have addList() to return a value (and you can get rid of the pointer to pointer).

Comment: thank you very much! i have noticed it and your absolutely right that was the problem